# Cant use find on element textarea which is child of td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I get an error on the line `targetTD[6].find('textarea').text()` saying  *targetTD[6].find is not a function. (In 'targetTD[6].find('textarea')', 'targetTD[6].find' is undefined)*

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(document.body).on('click','.edit',function () {// use button class ince ID has to be unique per button
                    var targetTD;              
                    if( $(this).find('i').hasClass('glyphicon-edit'))
                    {         
                        targetTD = $(this).parents('tr').find('td');  // gives all TDs of current row
                        if (targetTD[6].firstChild.children.length)   // the value cell is what we want
                        {
//                            targetTD[6].firstChild.children.item().setAttribute('readonly','false');                            
                              alert(targetTD[6].find('textarea').text());
                        }
```

I am trying to find a text area within a `<td><div> <textarea readonly> some text </textarea><div><td>`. How can I remove the `readonly` property ? Why cant I use find ?

Comment: Try `$(targetTD[6]).find`.  You're trying to call a jQuery function on the DOM object.

Comment: great ! thanks man. Still getting my feet wet with JQuery and DOM Stuff

Comment: Add the relevant HTML code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace:

```
targetTD[6].find('textarea').text();
```

With:

```
$(targetTD[6]).find('textarea').text();
```

Because targetTD is an array with not wrapped elements. Also, to remove readonly property use:

```
$(targetTD[6]).attr("readonly", false);
```

Answer (score -1):

`targetTD[6]` is a native JavaScript node. You need to wrap it in a jQuery selector `$()`

Like so: `$(targetTD[6]).find`